# Any finitely presented group is the fundamental group of some topological space？

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have come across a problem in topology as described in the title. 
Here is my intuitive construction with analogy to the fundamental group of closed surfaces.
Let $G=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n \mid r_1,r_2,\dots,r_m)$
 be a finitely presented group, then let $l^i$ be the length of each reduced word $r^i$, I define a polygon with $l^1+l^2+\dots+ l^m$ sides, and separately identify each $l^i$ sides as the reduced word $r^i$ suggests. Say, if $r^i = a_1 a_2 a_1 a_2$, then identify the consecutive $l^i$ sides by $a_1 a_2 a_1 a_2$. Then I guess that the identification space we construct is the required topological space, whose fundamental group is $G$. However, this is only an intuitive way, and I don't know whether it is right.

Moreover, can anyone explain to me the details of amalgamation when applying the Van Kampen theorem to closed surfaces? I don't understand why the amalgamation of two groups is the pushout of free products.
Your help would be sincerely appreciated, and sorry for my bad typing.

Comment: You *can* use LaTeX here!

Comment: It would be best f you asked a separate question for the second part («Moreover...»), which is rather disconnected with the first.

Comment: Dear user, Although it is not the main thrust of your question, you may be interested to know that any f.p. group can in fact be realized as the $\pi_1$ of a compact smooth $4$-manifold. (Of course, this $4$-manifold might have non-trivial higher homotopy groups.)  Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your construction is close but not quite right. For example, suppose we start with the silly presentation $\langle x:x^2, x^2\rangle$. Then the fundamental group of your space if $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

The standard construction adds one polygon *per relation*. Your start with a wedge of circles, one per generator, and then glue a polygon per relation. The resulting thing is sometimes called the presentation complex; googling that should find you more detailed descriptions.

Comment: Your answer is of great help to me, now I understand how it works to compute a fundamental group for a given 'well-glued' polygon surface. But I am still in puzzle what exactly 'one polygon per relation' is constructed for a given wedge of circles, whose number equals the generator of the given free group. Could you please offer some details or some references that I can consult? Thanks a lot